# I am not able to pass any object data in GoogleAccountCredential while syncing & creating events with Google Calendar API

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

```
 GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    private static final String[] SCOPES = {CalendarScopes.CALENDAR};

    public class CalendarAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService =    null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;
        private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            CalendarScopes.all();
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName("ridhsk13@gmail.com");
            //mCredential.setSelectedAccount(credentials);
            // String emailName = SignActivity.getPref(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, getContext());
            mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    getContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff()).setSelectedAccountName("ridhsk13@gmail.com");

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                    .setApplicationName("Call Google Calendar API")
                    .build();
```

The following is the data i want to pass in the google event

```
   String mainDate = params[0];
            String plus1Date = params[1];
            String plus2Date = params[2];
            String minus1Date = params[3];
            String minus2Date = params[4];
            // String summary = params[5];
            // String desc = params[6];

            String[] descr = {"BCG \n BCG vaccine to be given to the baby during birth \n Vaccines: BCG \n OPV 1 \n HepB 1",
                    "6 weeks completed\n These vaccine to be given after 6-8weeks of birth of baby: \n DTwP1\nIPV1\nHepB 2\nHiB1\nRotavirus1\nPVC1",
                    "10 weeks completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 10-12 weeks of birth : \n DTwP2\nIPV2\nHib2\nRotavirus2\nPCV2",
                    "14 weeks completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 14 weeks of birth :\nDTwP3\nIPV3\nHiB3\nRotavirus3\nPVC3",
                    "6 months completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 6 months of birth :\nOPV1\nHepB 3",
                    "9 months completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 9-12 months of birth :\nOPV 2\nMMR-1\n Typhoid Conjugate Vaccine",
                    "12 months completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 12 months of birth :\nHepA 1",
                    "15 months completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 15 months of birth :\nMMR 2\nVaricella 1\nPCV booster",
                    "16 months completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 16 months of birth :\nDTwP B1/DTaP B1\n IPV B1\nHib B1",
                    "18 months completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 18 months of birth :\nHep-A 2",
                    "2 years completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 2 years of birth :\nTyphoid booster",
                    "4 years completed \n Vaccines to be given to the baby after 4 years of birth :\nDTwP B2/DTaP B2\nOPV 3\nVaricella 2\nTyphoid booster"};



for (int j = 0; j < descr.length; j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                //for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                Event event = new Event()
                        .setSummary("I Vaccine")
                        .setDescription(descr[j]);

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append(params[i]).append("T09:00:00+05:30");

                DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(builder.toString());
                //DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2016-08-28T09:00:00+05:30");
                EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                        .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                        .setTimeZone("Asia/India");
                event.setStart(start);

                StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
                builder2.append(params[i]).append("T17:00:00+05:30");

                DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(builder2.toString());
                // DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2016-08-28T17:00:00+05:30");
                EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                        .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                        .setTimeZone("Asia/India");
                event.setEnd(end);

                String[] recurrence = new String[]{"RRULE:FREQ=Daily;COUNT=2"};
                event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

                EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[]{
                        new EventAttendee().setEmail("sgrkoli2@gmail.com"),
                };
                event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

                EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[]{
                        new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
                        new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(2),
                };
                Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                        .setUseDefault(false)
                        .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
                event.setReminders(reminders);
```

And this is the Permission Code fro syncing with the Google Account

```
String calendarId = "primary";
                    try {
                        event = mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                        //mLastError = e;
                        startActivityForResult(
                                e.getIntent(),
                                RegisterFragment.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
```

And this my logcat:

```
09-02 14:23:49.793 16508-16508/com.example.macminii5.framelayout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.macminii5.framelayout, PID: 16508
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.facetleon.ridhamsagar.ivaccine.RegisterFragment$CalendarAsyncTask.doInBackground(RegisterFragment.java:924)
                                                                                       at com.facetleon.ridhamsagar.ivaccine.RegisterFragment.calculateDates(RegisterFragment.java:289)
                                                                                       at com.facetleon.ridhamsagar.ivaccine.RegisterFragment$3.onClick(RegisterFragment.java:203)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What's going wrong?
Answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your [error] means that you are invoking the method `connect()` on the object `mGoogleApiClient` without instantiating it. This [sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) shows how to handle the Google Calendar API call. Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive. Here's also a [tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential) might help on how to use `GoogleAccountCredential` class.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Yes i resolved this issue. I didn't used the connecting code with the APIs.